# Outlook add-ins are disabled for NDR mail messages (undeliverable mail), is it by design?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins

We just encountered that Outlook add-ins are disabled for specific NDR mails in a normal user mailbox. See screenshot.
Is this functionality by design or do we need to do anything in order to take care of such mail messages to enable these add-ins?
[image]

Comment: As Eugene mentioned in answer this is by design.

Comment: Replaced outlook-addin tag with outlook-web-addins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages, meeting requests, or appointments are supported only. Check out the [Office.Item interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.item?view=outlook-js-preview) for more information about supported items.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.